# save pylint message to a file

Tags: python, pylint

Is there a built in way to save the pylint report to a file? It seems it might be useful to do this in order to log progress on a project and compare elements of reports across multiple files as changes are made.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note: [**This option is deprecated and it will be removed in Pylint 2.0.**](https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/whatsnew/changelog.html#what-s-new-in-pylint-2-0)

You can use the `--file-output=y` command line option. Quoting the man page:

```
   --files-output=<y_or_n>
          Put messages in a separate file for each module / package speci‐
          fied  on  the  command  line instead of printing them on stdout.
          Reports  (if   any)   will   be   written   in   a   file   name
          "pylint_global.[txt|html]". [current: no]
```

The format of the output is specified by the  `--output-format=<format>` option where format can be `text`, `parseable`,  `colorized`,  `msvs`  (visual studio) and `html`.

Answer (score 12):

You can redirect its output in your shell using `> somefile.txt`
In case it writes to stderr, use `2>&1 > somefile.txt`

Comment: Can I both output to file, and still output to stdout? I'm just running the command twice on my build machine...

Comment: @DanCiborowski-MSFT pipe it into `tee somefile`; which will write to somefile and also print to stdout