# How to get the list of errors from pylint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I have a Python script called `my_code.py`. I am using:

```
import pylint

pylint.run_pylint(argv=["my_code.py"])
```

How to get all errors and store them in a **list** in the above snippet?

Comment: Isn't this literally covered by the docs over on https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development_guide/api/pylint.html? But really: run it as a command with all the flags you need to get the output you need, and then capture its stdout output. It's _meant_ to be used as command line utility, not really "in a script" (even if you _technically_ can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75509541/12470058), one way is to get the `json` report and iterate through it.

```
import json
from io import StringIO
from pylint.lint import Run
from pylint.reporters import JSONReporter

reporter = StringIO()
Run(["my_code.py"], reporter=JSONReporter(reporter), do_exit=False)
results = json.loads(reporter.getvalue())
errors = {}
for i in results:
    errors[i.get('message-id')] = i.get('message')

for k, v in errors.items():
    print(k, v)
```

This will print each error code and the corresponding message.

For example, if you have `my_code.py` as follows:

```
def foo(l: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    return l[1:]
```

then after running my solution, you will get:

```
C0304 Final newline missing
C0114 Missing module docstring
C0116 Missing function or method docstring
C0104 Disallowed name "foo"
C0103 Argument name "l" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style
E0602 Undefined variable 'List'
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted some code that found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081299/how-to-get-report-score-from-pylint-when-run-python-code):

```py
from io import StringIO
from pylint.lint import Run
from pylint.reporters import text

def main():
    pylint_opts = ["--reports=n", "toto.py"]
    pylint_output = StringIO()
    reporter = text.TextReporter(pylint_output)
    Run(pylint_opts, reporter=reporter, do_exit=False)
    a = pylint_output.getvalue()
    print(a.split("\n"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Another option would be to write output to a file and then [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439481/save-pylint-message-to-a-file) it.

Answer (score 0):

When we run as normal like you did:

```py
import pylint

pylint.run_pylint(argv=["knowde_com.py"])
```

output:

```
************* Module knowde_com
knowde_com.py:37:0: C0301: Line too long (105/100) (line-too-long)
knowde_com.py:43:0: C0301: Line too long (104/100) (line-too-long)
knowde_com.py:128:0: C0301: Line too long (117/100) (line-too-long)
knowde_com.py:157:0: C0301: Line too long (115/100) (line-too-long)
knowde_com.py:25:0: C0115: Missing class docstring (missing-class-docstring)
knowde_com.py:57:4: R0914: Too many local variables (23/15) (too-many-locals)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 8.24/10 (previous run: 8.24/10, +0.00)
```

To get it all into a list, Here's a **simple solution**:

```py
import subprocess

command = "pylint knowde_com.py"
result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
result_list = result.stdout.split('\n')[1:-5]
print(result_list)
```

output:

```
['knowde_com.py:37:0: C0301: Line too long (105/100) (line-too-long)', 'knowde_com.py:43:0: C0301: Line too long (104/100) (line-too-long)', 'knowde_com.py:128:0: C0301: Line too long (117/100) (line-too-long)', 'knowde_com.py:157:0: C0301: Line too long (115/100) (line-too-long)', 'knowde_com.py:25:0: C0115: Missing class docstring (missing-class-docstring)', 'knowde_com.py:57:4: R0914: Too many local variables (23/15) (too-many-locals)']
```